# How to learn and create speech recognition system?

Tags: machine-learning, speech-recognition

I wanted to create a speech recognition system for Punjabi language for my personal project, i am willing to learn it, read any book even if it takes a year's time.

Can someone experienced here guide me towards the right direction.
It will be a lot of help to me.

I have knowledge of programming and can code if required, but i really don't know from where to start, all i know that is it requires extensive use of Machine Learning, and i am learning tensor flow for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purpose, it makes sense to use a pre-existing framework. Creating a speech recognition engine from scratch will not be worth your time with all the existing engines/frameworks out there. Years of research have gone into creating many of the frameworks that exist today. Something like Kaldi would be good. Here are two pages you may want to check out:

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-start-learning-speech-recognition-algorithms

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-use-KALDI-speech-recognition-toolkit-to-build-our-own-Automatic-Speech-Recognition-System

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Also i thank the down voter of my question, he really inspires me to work more :)